# Compiling VLCKit on OS X 10.8.2

Tags: xcode, macos, vlc, libvlc

I am trying to build VLCKit on OS X 10.8.2. I've installed the latest Xcode as of today (2013.01.27). What I did so far:

```
git clone git://git.videolan.org/vlc-bindings/VLCKit.git
cd VLCKit
xcodebuild -alltargets -configuration Release -project VLCKit.xcodeproj ARCHS="x86_64" -sdk macosx10.8
```

After some time, I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_iconv", referenced from:
      _sub_recode in libass.a(ass.o)
      _FcSfntNameTranscode in libfontconfig.a(fcfreetype.o)
  "_iconv_close", referenced from:
      _sub_recode in libass.a(ass.o)
      _FcSfntNameTranscode in libfontconfig.a(fcfreetype.o)
  "_iconv_open", referenced from:
      _sub_recode in libass.a(ass.o)
      _FcSfntNameTranscode in libfontconfig.a(fcfreetype.o)
  CCLD     libtelx_plugin.la
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[4]: *** [liblibass_plugin.la] Error 1
make[4]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[3]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Am I missing something? How can I compile VLCKit on 10.8.2? Please help!

Comment: looks like it's missing the iconv binding somehow ("-liconv") ...

Answer (score 1):

Try cloning this repo instead:

```
git clone git://git.videolan.org/vlc/vlc-2.0.git
```

Then build with:

```
cd vlc-2.0/projects/macosx/framework/
xcodebuild -target "Build Everything" -configuration Release -project VLCKit.xcodeproj ARCHS="x86_64" -sdk macosx10.6
```

It's unlikely to work first time so read these instruction all the way through - particularly the troubleshooting section

http://wiki.videolan.org/OSXCompile

I've just built the VLCKit 2.06 and am having some problems playing UDP streams. For me the solution, temporarily was to use the old stable branch here:

```
git clone git://git.videolan.org/vlc/vlc-1.1.git
```